# jQuery's noConflict: Just a quick thought

Tags: closures, jquery

The documentation says you can use $.noConflict() like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) { 
  $(function() {
    // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
// other code using $ as an alias to the other library
```

It also states that calling it returns an instance of the jQuery object, so I could do this:

```
jQuery.noConflict()(function(){
    // code using jQuery
}); 
// other code using $ as an alias to the other library
```

However, is this combination valid?

```
(function($) { 
  $(function() {
    // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery.noConflict());
// other code using $ as an alias to the other library
```

If so, is there a reason to not do it this way?  And also (if it works), why not always use this method to guarantee that inside of our closure, $ == jQuery?

Comment: The only downside I see is that if you have multiple blocks like that, you'd be unnecessarily calling `jQuery.noConflict()` more than once. Admittedly, that's not a very significant downside.

Comment: @Wiseguy Yeah I think you'd just do it on the first closure, otherwise it is a bit of a waste.

Comment: Then you'd have to keep track of which block is the first loaded. What if you later add a block/include a .js file above the previous first one? I'd just as well have `<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>` at the very top and just use `(function($){})(jQuery)` throughout. Basically boils down to personal preference, I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last method works as well - `jQuery.noConflict()` returns the jQuery object, which is passed as the `$` argument to the function.

I don't see a reason to not do it that way and would prefer it to the other methods.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see why not since `jQuery.noConflict` [returns](http://www.google.com/codesearch#vcrNNWaA4DY/trunk/MazoviaFutsalTeam/webapp/Webapp/Scripts/jquery-1.7.js&type=cs&l=391) the `jQuery` object and it's evaluated before the function is called.